# How to test Doctrine Entity Manager findOneById method with prophecy?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm using prophecy to write my unit tests

```
"require": {
    ...,
    "phpspec/prophecy-phpunit": "~1.0"
},
```

and I have a call to

```
 $dbUser = $this
            ->em
            ->getRepository('MainBundle:User')
            ->findOneById($id);
```

when testing this I get an error because the method findOneByProperty is not defined. Except from changing the original code into :

```
 $dbUser = $this
            ->em
            ->getRepository('MainBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id);
```

i did not find any other workaround. 
Is there any way you can test this using prophecy and keeping the original code?

Comment: It seems that you have to use [MagicCallPatch](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/blob/master/src/Prophecy/Doubler/ClassPatch/MagicCallPatch.php) but I have no idea how those are applied (never been using prophecy, but was curious to understand how to mock magic methods) and I can't find any documentation

Comment: Is prophecy required for do this?

Comment: This question and the last one seem like questions that could do with more eyes. Would you like a bounty on one of them? If so, which needs looking at most?

Answer (score 3):

If by "*original code*" you meant the **client** code, you can workaround this by creating a custom entity repository.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneById(int $id)
    {
        return parent::findOneById($id);
    }
}
```

For reference http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

And in your tests

```
$userRepository = $this->prophesize(UserRepository::class);

$em = $this->prophesize(EntityManagerInterface::class);
$em->getRepository('MainBundle:User')->willReturn($userRepository->reveal());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use find() when you searching by primary key. So, your code can be as simple as this:

```
$dbUser = $this
           ->em
           ->getRepository('MainBundle:User')
           ->find($id);
```

[See here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) for more information.